# Non privileged user launch SSH?

Tags: ssh, unprivileged

My server got hacked, and as a result the server guys decided that my apache user would be one called 'nonpriv' which has no privileges at all.

Before that happened, I had a user that run apache which had lots of privileges. I used that user to launch a script which does several SSH connections.  I have a UI that lets users in my system to launch that script. However now, since the Apache user does not have privileges, he can't perform those SSH calls.

I tried several things:

1 - Make my apache user to do the SSH calls. But oh, this non privileged user doesn't even have a shell.
2 - Make my apache user to tell the other user to do the calls, but not working.
3 - Researched on named pipes so that these two users can somehow communicate, but is confusing.

So my question is:

- How do you deal in these situations? If your apache user doesn't have privileges, but you need that from a web application launch a script that does SSH calls.

Comment: Who are "the server guys"?

Comment: Please explain what your script is doing. Are the ssh calls necessary? There may be another way around it. If you have a sysadmin (I am guessing that's the "Server guys") why don't you ask _them_?